# Непроизносимые согласные в корне слов "ехидство", "щуриться", "экскаватор"

Tags: правописание

Подскажите, пожалуйста, являются ли слова *ехидство, щуриться, экскаватор, юмористка, юношество* словами с непроизносимой согласной в корне слова? И есть ли здесь вообще непроизносимые согласные?

Answer (score 1):

Надо сначала дать четкое определение "непроизносимым согласным". Если считать, что это ПРОПУСК звука (чередование его с нулем), то непроизносимых согласных здесь нет, но происходит взаимное изменение согласных звуков (ассимиляция/уподобление), два звука могут произносится каК один звук.

Ехидство (ДС/Ц), щуриться (ТЬС/Ц), экскаватор (все звуки, в том числе звук К, произносятся), юмористка (звук Т произносится, произношение без Т устаревшее), юношество (все звуки произносятся).

Но набор этих слов относится к теме непроизносимые/лишние согласные, так как возможны ошибки в написании и произношении. Такие слова желательно проверять по орфоэпическому словарю, например: явственный, здесь звук В произносится, хотя обычно пропускается в сочетании ВСТВ (чувство).

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, только в слове "ехидство" в корне есть непроизносимая согласная "д", которая вместе с "с" передает звук "ц" (ихицтва)

Comment: А в целом в этих словах есть непроизносимые согласные?

Comment: В слове "щуриться" вместо "т" и "сь" произносится "ц", но это суффиксы. В слове "юмористка" не произносится "т", но тоже в суффиксе

Comment: Иногда слово "экскаватор" произносят, как пишет Людмила, без "к" в первом случае. Но мне кажется, что это скорее похоже на пароним по отношению к другому, похожему слову "эскалатор"

Answer (score 0):

В этих словах нет непроизносимых согласных.

Comment: Капс не используйте и пишите подробнее.